# Persistent object with Django?

Tags: python, json, django, mysql-python

So I have a site that on a per-user basis, and it is expected to query a very large database, and flip through the results. Due to the size of the number of entries returned, I run the query once (which takes some time...), store the result in a global, and let folks iterate through the results (or download them) as they want.

Of course, this isn't scalable, as the globals are shared across sessions. What is the correct way to do this in Django? I looked at session management, but I always ran into the "xyz is not serializeable on json" issue. Do I look into how I do this correctly using sessions, or is there another preferred way to do this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a caching layer? Memcached, redis, etc

Comment: is it the same query for everybody?

Comment: you could use the db as the caching layer - take the results of the initial "hard work" query and save them in a new table... it will then be fast to retrieve results from that table and you can still filter them further via SQL/ORM, which is something you'd give up if you used a separate caching layer (and avoids the whole serialization problem too)

Comment: you ought to also consider that Django ORM does not grab all rows when you run the query (unless you force it to by doing something like `list(queryset)`) it will use cursors and get pages of results from the db as you iterate through the queryset

Answer (score 1):

If the user is flipping through the results, you probably don't want to pull back and render any more than you have to. Most SQL dialects have `TOP` and `LIMIT` clauses that will let you pull back a limited range of results, as long as your data is ordered consistently. Django's Pagination classes are a nice abstraction of this on top of Django Model classes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/

I would be careful of storing large amounts of data in user sessions, as it won't scale as your number of users grows, and user sessions can stay around for a while after the user has left the site. If you're set on this option, make sure you read about clearing the expired sessions. Django doesn't do it for you: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/#clearing-the-session-store